# Proof of greatest integer function f(x)=[x]

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $[x]$ be the greatest integer ≤ x

(a) Prove that $f(x) = [x]$ is a step function on any closed interval [a, b].

(b) Prove that $\int_{0}^{n}[x]dx = \frac{n(n−1)}2 \space \forall \space n \in \mathbb{Z}$ .

For (a), I understand that for any $x$ greater than $[x]$, they will be equal to the value of that integer. Then it's the definition of step function. But I don't know how to write a formal proof for it. For (b), if I can prove (a), I can use the induction to get (b).

Comment: Start with the textbook definition of a step function.  If you are still having trouble, please edit your query to include pertinent definitions/theorems and show your work.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT for b)**

$$\int_0^n[x]dx=\int_0^nxdx-\int_0^n{\lbrace x \rbrace}dx=\frac{n^2}{2}-n\int_0^1{\lbrace x \rbrace}dx=\frac{n^2}{2}-n.\frac{1}{2}.1.1$$

Comment: I simply used induction for b. Could you give me some hints for a?

Comment: @Kylinny Try plotting $[x]$.